# Protagonist modified to look like a neanderthal, also a riddle about catching a bird without caging it

Tags: story-identification, novel

This was the second book in the series I read about a decade or two ago.

The colony experience a famine after terrorist blew up a factory. The protagonist is on some spiritual journey and was modified to look like a neanderthal. There is also a riddle on how to catch a bird without clipping it's wings. The spaceships are also completely made out of diamond. At some point the protagonist looks at his thoughts on a screen and amuses an audience by thinking of a theorem.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  If you look at the [suggestions for asking questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) you might remember some more details you can [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/202791/edit) into your question.  For example, what language was it in, do you remember what the cover looked like?

Comment: I don't understand the riddle. How do you clip the wings of the bird without catching it?

Comment: Friend your op does not match your title

Answer (score 4):

"How do you catch a beautiful bird without killing its spirit?" is a kind of koan asked of Danlo wi Soli Ringess in the *Requiem for Homo Sapiens* trilogy by David Zindell which comes after the events in *Neverness*.

I The Broken God, 1992; II The Wild, 1995; III War in Heaven, 1998.

Both Danlo & his father, Mallory who is the central character in *Neverness* are sculpted to look like neanderthals.

Answer (score 1):

There are elements of this that remind me of Neverness by David Zindell, it got the Neanderthals and the math elements at least.